# Mini buildings in SimCity (2013)

Tags: simcity-2013

In SimCity, when I zone land for residential, commercial and industrial, sometimes there is not enough space at the end of the zone to fit another building. Occasionally, these little strips of land appear, sometimes with a building or a fence. You can not click on these but you can destroy them. I have not found any information about them. Could somebody enlighten me?

Here is a screenshot that I [found online](https://gamerhorizon.com/2013/01/29/simcity-closed-beta-impressions/):

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

The fence next to the residential building is an example, as is the fence next to the commercial building.

Comment: Pictures? (5 more to go...)

Comment: They are uncommon so let me find a picture.

Comment: @BaldBantha Updates question with an image

Comment: I rolled your "EDIT:" into the text. There's no need to signal edits on Arqade because all previous versions of a post are stored in the revision history (click on "edited X ago").

Comment: Here's an old image that I have of these buildings after a mass fire event: http://i.imgur.com/rKmFFno.jpg  You can bulldoze them, but they tend to reappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an official name for these things, but I call them "filler" or "junk". They appear when the game doesn't think there's enough room to put an actual building there (most obvious in industrial zones, given most such buildings need more room to exist).

They have no function and no purpose aside from making the land look less empty, but they can affect the logic of placing new buildings - if you're unlucky, a new or upgrading building will avoid running them over, which can result in an inefficient packing. In fact, in [my experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118063/do-i-have-to-monitor-the-junk-that-fills-in-empty-space), the game loves to put a single industrial building in a block and fill the remaining half with two units of junk, before it tries to fit a second building in there. It's a pain.

You can bulldoze junk with no penalty in an attempt to make the game try to fit an actual building there, but chances seem about 50/50 that a new piece of filler will just pop back up, and you have to be careful about accidentally destroying an actual building. They can go away on their own but to be honest I've never caught it.